# Search API - search string with "0" prefix

Tags: search

I have a problem with search api. I'm using database search + search api views integration in my website.
Everything works fine, but i noticed that when i submit the search form with a query like "0012" the "0" character is ignored and therefor the results are not correct.
It seems that something is converting the string into integer, stripping the 0 characters.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which field has this value? How is indexed (string, fulltext, etc)?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback. The exposed search acts on several fields, all indexed "fulltext".

Comment: Which filters have you enabled?

Comment: in my search view configuration, i have exposed the fulltext search. The views shows the file entities of my website, and I configured the index to allow the search to work. I can search fields like filename, mimetype, and other fields like tags (taxonomies). All these fields are indexed as "fulltext"

Comment: I'm talking about filter on your search api index :) Try to disable all filters

Comment: ah sorry :p all filters are already disabled... still not working

Comment: I don't know :( the problem appears only if the field starts with "000"?

Comment: yes, it works perfectly unless I add a "0" or "00" as prefix of my search string. I don't really know how to solve this problem